# Confused about class notes on gradient inequality and how to derive version for functions with compact support

Tags: analysis, functional-analysis, partial-differential-equations

I'm taking a grad analysis class, and I'm a little confused about how to show the basic gradient inequality for smooth functions with compact support.

Here is my professor's statement of the basic gradient inequality for functions smooth on a domain (but not necessarily with compact support):

Let $\Omega$ be a convex domain in $\mathbb{R}^{n}$. Then, $\forall u \in C^{\infty}(\Omega)$, $\forall x \in \Omega$, we have the following:
$\int |u(x)-u(y)|dy \leq \frac{(diam\,\Omega)^{n}}{n}\int_{\Omega}\frac{|Du(y)|}{|x-y|^{n-1}}dy$.

Now, from here, our professor said it would be a good exercise for us to try to derive the following corollary:

Corollary: Assume that $u \in C^{\infty}_{0}(\mathbb{R}^{n})$ (so, it is now not only smooth, but also has compact support inside $\mathbb{R}^{n}$.) Then, $|u(x)|\leq c_{n}\int_{\mathbb{R}^{n}}\frac{|Du(y)|}{|x-y|^{n-1}}$, where $c_{n}$ is a constant dependent on $n$.

He gave us the following hint: Apply the basic gradient inequality with $\Omega=B_{R}(0)$ (the ball centered at $0$ of radius $R$), and let $R \to \infty$.

Now, I'm not sure I entirely understand what's going on here, let alone how to apply that hint. But, what I am thinking is, if $u$ has compact support, we can think of that compact support as sitting inside one of these balls. But, then $\frac{(diam\,\Omega)^{n}}{n}=\frac{(2R)^{n}}{n}$, if we let $R \to \infty$, then how can this be a constant dependent on $n$?

Please don't be snarky, although I'm sure it's tempting from how lost I probably sound. I genuinely just want to learn, so if I'm approaching this problem all wrong, kindly tell me so and point me in the right direction. I am in some desperate need of help on this proof!

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Edit. Integrating the triangle inequality

$|u(x)| \leq |u(x)-u(y)| + |u(y)|$

over $y\in B_R(0)$, denoting the volume of the ball $|B_R(0)|=\omega_nR^n$, we get

$|u(x)| \leq \frac{1}{R^n \omega_n}\int_{B_R(0)}|u(x)-u(y)|dy + \frac{C}{R^n \omega_n}$

where $C=\int_\Omega |u(y)|dy=\mathrm{const}$. Now use the known gradient inequality and let $R\to \infty$...

Comment: Why are we justified in dropping the second term? Also, how am I going to get the RHS to be $\leq c_{n}\int_{\mathbb{R}^{n}}\frac{|Du(y)|}{|x-y|^{n-1}}$?

Comment: Sorry, I used the triangle inequality the wrong way. See the edited version

Comment: One last little follow up. The only thing that's still bothering me is this: you used the triangle inequality on $|u(x)|=|u(x)+u(y)-u(y)|\leq |u(x)-u(y)|+|u(y)|$, and then integrated the RHS if this inequality without integrating the LHS. It, therefore, appears to me that the RHS is greater than or equal to $\frac{1}{R^{n}\omega_{n}}\int_{B_{R}(0)}|u(x)|$ and not $|u(x)|$ itself. What am I missing here (and then I'll leave you alone; I promise! ;) )

Comment: Both sides were integrated $dy$. LHS is constant with respect to $y$ and therefore the integral of the LHS is just $|B_R(0)| \cdot |u(x)|$. The inequality is obtained when you divide both sides by the volume of the ball.

Comment: Gotcha. Thank you so very much!